# How to generate the IAM access tokens for analytics engine requests using python?

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

The [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsEngine/provisioning.html#provisioning-an-ibm-analytics-engine-service-instance) for Analytics Engine provides a link to generate a IAM access tokens using the CLI, but I need to generate the token with an API call.  This is the CLI approach:

```
bx api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
bx login
<enter your credentials>

<If you are part of multiple IBM Cloud accounts, you'll be asked to choose an account for the current session. Also, you'll need to choose an organization and space in IBM Cloud.>

bx iam oauth-tokens
```

The documentation also states that the Cloud Foundry API is deprecated? How can I generate the IAM access tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I created in the end ...

Some utility classes for logging and exceptions:

```py
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import logging
import os 

class Logger:

    def __init__(self):
        format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        logging.basicConfig(format=format)
        self.ch = logging.StreamHandler()

    def get_logger(self, clazz):
        logger = logging.getLogger(clazz)
        logger.setLevel(os.getenv("LOG_LEVEL", logging.INFO))
        return logger

class CloudFoundryException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message, *args):
        self.message = message
        super(CloudFoundryException, self).__init__(message, *args)
```

Then a class to do the main work:

```py
class CloudFoundryAPI(object):

    def __init__(self, api_key=None, api_key_filename=None, api_endpoint='https://api.ng.bluemix.net', provision_poll_timeout_mins=30):

        self.log = Logger().get_logger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.provision_poll_timeout_mins = provision_poll_timeout_mins 

        assert api_key is not None or api_key_filename is not None, "You must provide a value for api_key or for api_key_filename"

        # allow tests to override the api_key_filename parameter
        if hasattr(CloudFoundryAPI, 'api_key_filename') and CloudFoundryAPI is not None:
            api_key_filename = CloudFoundryAPI.api_key_filename

        if api_key_filename is not None:
            try:
                with open(api_key_filename, 'r') as api_file:
                    d = json.load(api_file)
                    try:
                        self.api_key = d['apikey']
                    except KeyError:
                        # The attibute name used to be
                        self.api_key = d['apiKey']

            except:
                self.log.error('Error retrieving "apiKey" from file {}'.format(api_key_filename))
                raise
        else:
            self.api_key = api_key

        self.api_endpoint = api_endpoint
        self.info = self._get_info()

    def auth(self):
        self.log.debug('Authenticating to CloudFoundry')
        url = self.info['authorization_endpoint'] + '/oauth/token'
        headers = { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
                    'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8', 
                    'Authorization': 'Basic Y2Y6'
                }
        data = 'grant_type=password&username=apikey&password={}'.format(self.api_key)
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
            response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            self.log.error('Cloud Foundry Auth Response: ' + response.text)
            # TODO we should define a custom application exception for this
            raise

        self.auth_token = response.json()
        self.expires_at = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=self.auth_token['expires_in']/60)
        self.log.debug('Authenticated to CloudFoundry')

    def oidc_token(self):

        self.log.debug('Retrieving IAM token')

        url='https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token'
        data="grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey&apikey={}".format(self.api_key)

        try:
            response = requests.post(url, data=data)
            response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            self.log.debug('IAM token response: ' + response.text)
            raise

        self.oidc_token = response.json()
        self.oidc_expires_at = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=self.oidc_token['expires_in']/60)
        self.log.debug('Retrieved IAM token')
        return self.oidc_token

    def get_auth_token(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'auth_token') or not hasattr(self, 'expires_at') or datetime.now() > self.expires_at:
            self.auth()
        return self.auth_token

    def get_oidc_token(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'oidc_token') or not hasattr(self, 'oidc_expires_at') or datetime.now() > self.oidc_expires_at:
            self.oidc_token()
        return self.oidc_token

    def _request_headers(self):

        auth_token = self.get_auth_token()
        access_token = auth_token['access_token']
        token_type = auth_token['token_type']

        headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'authorization': '{} {}'.format(token_type, access_token),
            'cache-control': 'no-cache', 
            'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        return headers

    def _request(self, url, http_method='get', data=None, description='', create_auth_headers=True):
        if create_auth_headers:
            headers = self._request_headers()
        else:
            headers = {}
        try:
            if http_method == 'get':
                response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            elif http_method == 'post':
                response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
            elif http_method == 'delete':
                response = requests.delete(url, headers=headers)

            response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            self.log.error('{} : {} {} : {} {}'.format(description, http_method, url, response.status_code, response.text))
            raise CloudFoundryException(message=response.text)

        try:
            self.log.debug('{} : {} {} : {} {}'.format(description, http_method, url, response.status_code, json.dumps(response.json())))
        except ValueError:
            self.log.debug('{} : {} {} : {} {}'.format(description, http_method, url, response.status_code, response.text))

        return response

    def _get_info(self):
        url = '{}/v2/info'.format(self.api_endpoint)
        response = self._request(url=url, http_method='get', description='_get_info', create_auth_headers=False)
        return response.json()
```

You can then use it like so:

```py
cf = CloudFoundryAPI(api_key="xxxx") # or pass api_key_filename
cf.get_auth_token() # get UAA token
cf.get_oidc_token() # get IAM token
```